# Stop Httpd to take updated COM component

Tags: com, asp-classic, windows-ce, apache

I am working with ASP pages in WIN CE device. The web server is httpd. We have developed a COM for using in the ASP pages. Now we are facing an issue. The issue is once we loaded the home page and used the `COM` component, the httpd will not take newer version of COM we put. We currently restart the device for the httpd to take an updated COM component.

How can we correct the issue? Is it possible to stop httpd service and restart?.if yes, how?
We have limited ActiveSync capability using ConmanClient2.exe and cMaccept.exe

Comment: Hey @Maanu, I was wondering if you have some links to info on how you developed the COM component, I have to do some of that and I am having a hard time finding documentation. Did you do it in C or C#? Is it just a simple COM component like you would develop for a full windows, or is there anything special about it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the command-line processor on the device you can do

`services stop htp0:`
`services start htp0:`

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in restarting this service during development of your COM object you can use the Windows CE Remote Process Viewer provided with Visual Studio Remote Tools to terminate the process, and then start it again manually. During WinCE applications development I have found [SOTI Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/Default.aspx) to be useful. I am not related to them in any way, I am just a happy user of this tool.

If you are also interested in a programmatic solution, you can [enumerate all services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450368.aspx) programmatically, [terminate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450329.aspx) the httpd process and [launch it again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450278.aspx). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450232.aspx) for more details.

Regarding ConmanClient2.exe and cMaccept.exe, these are Visual Studio tools and they are not related to ActiveSync, you can use them with WiFi or Ethernet even when there is no ActiveSync support on your device..